# what is definition of homotopy of homeomorphisms and isotopy of homeomorphisms?

Tags: general-topology, definition, homotopy-theory, mapping-class-group

I read "A Primer on Mapping Class Groups"
By Benson Farb, Dan Margalit.

I can't find definition of **homotopy of homeomorphisms and isotopy of homeomorphisms** in this book but in this book we have definition of homotopy and of isotopy **simple closed curves**.

> what is definition of **homotopy of homeomorphisms and isotopy of homeomorphisms** in this book ? where is this definition ?

Comment: An homotopy of homeomorphisms is an homotopy $F:[0,1]\times M\to M$ between two homeomorphisms, i.e. $F(0,\cdot)$ and $F(1,\cdot)$ are homeomorphisms.
An isotopy of homeomorphism is an homotopy of homeomorphism plus the constraint that for each $t\in [0,1]$, $F(t,\cdot):M\to M$ is an homemorphism.

Comment: @WarlockofFiretopMountain is this in the book ?

Comment: I have no idea, are standard definitions in any case.

Comment: Regarding homotopy: The book expects you to know this definition since it is typically taught in an algebraic topology course.

Comment: Assuming that you have studied algebraic topology, then you certainly already know the definition of a homotopy of continuous functions. And then, since a homeomorphism is a special case of a continuous function, you therefore already know the meaning of a homotopy of homeomorphisms.